# Can solve my "SMTP Error: Could not authenticate" error

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, smtp-auth

i have a problem with my PHPmailer function.

I want my registration form to send a mail to every new registered member.

I get this error code. SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

I have contacted my webhost, and they say that i have the right username,password, smtp server etc.

```
        include "class.smtp.php";
        include "class.phpmailer.php";

        $Host = "mail.smtp.com";            // SMTP servers
        $Username = "support@mymail.com";   // SMTP password
        $Password = "mymailpassword";

        $From = "support@mymail.com";
        $FromName = "My name";

        $ToEmail = $mail;
        $ToName = $username;
        $header = str_replace('%homepage_url%', $hp_url, $_language->module['mail_subject']);
        $Message = str_replace(Array('%nickname%', '%username%', '%password%', '%activationlink%', '%pagetitle%', '%homepage_url%'), Array(stripslashes($nickname), stripslashes($username), stripslashes($pwd1), stripslashes($validatelink), $hp_title, $hp_url), $_language->module['mail_text']);

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->IsSMTP();                    // send via SMTP
        $mail->Host     = $Host; 
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;             // turn on SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = $Username;  
        $mail->Password = $Password; 

        $mail->From     = $From;
        $mail->FromName = $FromName;

        $mail->AddAddress($ToEmail , $ToName);

        $mail->WordWrap = 50;               // set word wrap
        $mail->Priority = 1; 
        $mail->IsHTML(true);  
        $mail->Subject  =  $header;

        $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
        $mail->MsgHTML($Message);

        $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";

        if(!$mail->Send()){
            redirect("index.php",$_language->module['register_successful'],10);
            $show = false;
        } else {
            redirect("index.php",$_language->module['register_successful'],10);
            $show = false;
        }
```

Comment: Have you verified with your host which Port they are using (25, 465, 587, etc) and tried specifying that as well? ie. `$mail->Port = 587;`

Comment: You've based your code on an obsolete example and you're using an old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and [read the documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` and post what it says in your question. Also disable your redirects while debugging; they will just get in the way.